# Google Chrome: How do I get my status bar back?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

This silly design of the status bar popping up and disappearing is really bothering me. I used to have a few good extensions on my status bar in Firefox (Pagerank, AdBlock, etc) and now they all have to be placed in strange locations on the toolbars near the top without easily displaying any relevant information.

Is there a way I can get the status bar back and use it similarly to FF?

**Edit:** I realize Chrome never had a status bar but just about all other browsers do and it's really awkward not to have one. I was hoping there was a way to make it have one.

Comment: Chrome never had a status bar, as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a Chrome extension that provides this, but I don't believe Chrome ever had a status bar.

Comment: Correct: Chrome has never had a permanent status bar.  It overlays one when hovering over URLs, but that's it.

Comment: It used to popup on hover or when there was relevant page activity (such as on page load/resource requests) so that when pages got stuck on loading because an external script request didn't reply one could see what request stalled.

This was however removed a while back, probably due to majority of all stalls being slow response from google-analytics.com and they didn't like chrome saying "Contacting google-analytics.com" for a long time virtually every time a page loaded slowly.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be an extension, chrome extensions have very limited capabilities. However, link targets are displayed on hover and extension buttons can display status info that gets updated on page loads.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no extension right now nor do I think there ever will be. Personally, I don't see much use in a status bar.

Comment: It's just where I usually put all of my extension icons because they don't really fit at the top

Answer (score 0):

It does have a status bar, it pops up when you mouseover a link or when a page has activity. Usually on the bottom left, kind of a floating status bar.

Answer (score -1):

Extensions will not serve in producing the status bar. This is one of the feature of chrome so you can make it appear every time

Comment: Feature? I don't understand what benefit it provides. You gain 10px back?